# Consuming payload with multipart/mixed Content-Type in Mule 4

Tags: mule, multipart, dataweave, mule4

I have to send a multipart/mixed request to an external API and I've built a Mule 4 flow in which an endpoint is configured to receive multipart/mixed payload. The endpoint I created should accept a multipart/mixed payload where the payload is like below as seen in the Postman screen.

Below is the flow xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
   <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP_Listener_config"  doc:id="d8e92a34-d34d-4e1a-abec-7405b9010241">
      <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
   </http:listener-config>
   <flow name="testmultipart-flow" doc:id="d8e92a34-d34d-4e1a-bce3-7405b9010241">
      <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="88476dbb-04af-429d-83f3-20714be8d406" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/multi" outputMimeType="multipart/mixed; boundary=batch" />
      <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="ccde0f6d-cc70-4b05-a68c-60f644381b1e" message="Payload: #[payload]" />
      <ee:transform doc:name="Multipart payload" doc:id="bfeeab27-6f01-4ea1-a46a-1a65c5aa0021">
         <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
         </ee:message>
      </ee:transform>
   </flow>
</mule>
```

Below is the curl code snippet for the POST request I'm making:

```
curl --location 'http://0.0.0.0:8081/multi/' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' \
--data '--batch
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET TDTREESET?$filter=(Field1%20eq%20'\''213123'\'')&format=xml HTTP/1.1

--batch-'
```

When I make the request, Mule flow is receiving an empty payload. I tried debugging it and I can see that there is nothing coming in for payload in Mule Debug mode. I tried setting the Mime Type as multipart/mixed and boundary as 'batch' in the flow listener, but still not receiving anything in payload.

```
payload =
^mediaType = multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8; boundary=batch
```

Here is the error I receive at the end of the flow.

```
"javax.mail.internet.ParseException - Missing start boundary
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing start boundary...
```

How can I get the payload that I'm sending in the request in raw Text as is in my Mule flow as the payload and why I'm getting this error even though I set the boundary?

Mule runtime version I'm using is 4.4.0-20211227

Comment: Please don't use images for textual information. For the payload instead of the debugger screenshot which provides very limited details you could use a logger. Your question should include a minimal reproducible example. In other words share your flow so others can reproduce the issue and understand exactly what you are doing. All this is explained in more details in the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page.

Comment: Also add the exact version of Mule 4 and patch level.

Answer (score 0):

Works correctly for me but I'm using Mule 4.4.0-20230724. Maybe your version lacks patches to handle this use case since it is an old patch version with almost 2 years of missed patches. Try with the latest patch or the latest minor release of Mule.

HTTP response body

```
{
  "parts": {
    "part0": {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/http",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
      },
      "content": "GET TDTREESET?$filter=(Field1%20eq%20'213123')&format=xml HTTP/1.1\n\n--batch-"
    }
  }
}
```

On a side note `outputMimeType="multipart/mixed; boundary=batch"` is redundant since the request already sets that content type.